# link_to in .js.erb file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

For some reason, when I use link_to in my show.js.erb file, the javascript does not work...

This works:

```
$(".commentvotecount<%= params[:commentid]%>").html("<%= positiveVoteCount = @comment.plusminus %>");
```

This doesn't:

```
$(".commentvotecount<%= params[:commentid]%>").html("<%= positiveVoteCount = @comment.plusminus %> <%= link_to 'About', '/about' %>");
```

What is going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use escape_javascript so quotes are escaped.

```
$(".commentvotecount<%= params[:commentid]%>").html("<%= escape_javascript link_to('About', '/about') %>");
```